# Error ordenando valores de un archivo binario

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
try{
    raf = new RandomAccessFile("Partides.dat", "rw");

    for (long i=0; i< "partides.dat".length(); i= i+48){

        for (long j=i +48; j<"partides.dat".length(); j=j+48){

            // Es llegueixen els valors de la posició punts
            raf.seek(i);
            double valorI= raf.readDouble();

            raf.seek(j);
            double valorJ = raf.readDouble();

            //Es comparen
            if (valorI > valorJ )
                //se intercanvian
                raf.seek(i);
            raf.writeDouble(valorJ);
            raf.seek(j);
            raf.writeDouble(valorI);
        }
    }
    raf.close();
```

No consigo que me ordene los registros que tengo.. y no sé que hago mal.. :S En este caso estoy intentando ordenar dos valores..

Básicamente con el código intento conseguir que me ordene unos datos que están posicionados en el 48 "es decir los puntos" de mayor a menor. Pero si entiendo bien mi código estoy intentando ordenar solo 2 valores.. no se si hay una forma de ordenar todos de otra manera.. :S

Pongo el código completo a revisión:

```js
/**
 * OPCIO 2  ACTIVITAT 3
 */
package activitat2;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
public class Opcio2 {
    /**
     * En aquesta clase farem les demandes de l'activitat 2
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    static void ActualitzarInstituts() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        RandomAccessFile raf;
        raf = new RandomAccessFile("Partides.dat", "rw");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("HAS ESCOLLIT OPCIÓ 2");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Escoge una opción:::::::");
        System.out.println("1-Actualizar Puntos y listar resultados");
        System.out.println("2-Instituto Ganador ");
        System.out.println("3-Percentatge dels millors instituts");
        System.out.println("4- Volver al menú principal");
        System.out.println("5- Salir");
        System.out.println("Escoje una opción");
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int punts=0;
        int enterLlegit =0;
        boolean llegit = false;
        while(!llegit){
            llegit = lector.hasNextInt();
            if (llegit){
                enterLlegit = lector.nextInt();
                switch (enterLlegit) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("HAS ESCOGIDO ACTUALIZAR PUNTOS");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");  
           for (int registro = 1;; registro++) {            
    int pos = 48 * (registro - 1);
    try {       
        pos += 4 + 20 + 20;
        // Lectura
        raf.seek(pos);
        System.out.printf("Instituto número: #%02d%n", registro);
        raf.seek(pos);
        System.out.printf("Puntos actuales: %d%n", raf.readInt());
        // Escritura
        raf.seek(pos);
        System.out.println("Introducir puntos: ");
         punts = lector.nextInt();
         System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        raf.writeInt(punts);
        raf.seek(pos);  
          } catch (EOFException e) {
        // Fin de archivo
        raf.close();
         System.out.println("Datos actualizados:::");
         System.out.println("Tornem al menú principal");
         Opcio1.IntroduirInstituts();
break;
    } }break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("HAS ESCOGIDO ORDENAR POR PUNTOS:");
             System.out.println("Instituto Ganador ");
             System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
             try{
                  raf = new RandomAccessFile("Partides.dat", "rw");
                 for (long i=0; i< "partides.dat".length(); i= i+48){
                     for (long j=i +48; j<"partides.dat".length(); j=j+48){

                         // Es llegueixen els valors de la posició punts
                         raf.seek(i);
                         double valorI= raf.readDouble();
                         raf.seek(j);
                         double valorJ = raf.readDouble();
                         //Es comparen
                         if (valorI > valorJ )                         
                             //se intercanvian
                             raf.seek(i);
                             raf.writeDouble(valorJ);
                             raf.seek(j);
                             raf.writeDouble(valorI);           
                         }
                     }raf.close();
                             //    ANEM A LLISTAR RESULTATS:
             System.out.println("Ves a la opción Listar para observar los cambios");
             Opcio1.IntroduirInstituts();

                 } catch (Exception e){
                     System.out.println("Error ordenado fichero");
                     }          
            break;

        case 3:
        System.out.println("Percentatge dels millors instituts");
        //PENDIENTE DE HACER //
            break;

             case 4:
            System.out.println("TORNAR AL MENÚ PRINCIPAL::::");
            MenuPrincipal.EscollirOpcio(); 
            break;

       case 5:
           System.out.println("HAS ESCOLLIT SORTIR");
System.out.println("Hasta la próxima!");
        break;      
        default:
System.out.println("No has escrito una opción válida");
System.out.println("Fin del programa");
        break;}
            }else{
                System.out.println("No has escrito un entero, vuelve a intentarlo");
                lector.next();
            }    
        }
        lector.nextLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías ordenar los registros utilizando la interfaz [`java.lang.Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) y la clase [`java.util.Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

Primeramente creas una clase que implementa la interfaz mencionada. Por ejemplo:

```
class Registro implements Comparable<Registro> {

    int id;
    String instituto;
    String equipo;
    int puntos;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Registro o) {
        return o.puntos - puntos;
    }
}
```

La implementación del método `compareTo` es utilizada en el proceso de ordenamiento.

Para almacenar todos los registros, se puede utilizar una lista, es decir, una instancia de [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
List<Registro> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

En un ciclo `for`, creas un `Registro`, lees lo datos correspondientes y los agregas a lista, hasta finalizar el archivo:

```
for (int pos = 0;;) {
    try {
        Registro registro = new Registro();
        raf.seek(pos);
        registro.id = raf.readInt();
        pos += 4;

        raf.seek(pos);
        registro.instituto = raf.readUTF();
        pos += 20;

        raf.seek(pos);
        registro.equipo = raf.readUTF();
        pos += 20;

        raf.seek(pos);
        registro.puntos = raf.readInt();
        pos += 4;
        list.add(registro);
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        // Fin de archivo
        break;
    }
}
```

Ordenas la lista usando el método `sort` de la clase `java.util.Collections`:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Una vez ordenados, escribes en el archivo los registros con otro ciclo `for`:

```
for (int i = 0, pos = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Registro registro = list.get(i);
    raf.seek(pos);
    raf.writeInt(registro.id);
    pos += 4;

    raf.seek(pos);
    raf.writeUTF(registro.instituto);
    pos += 20;

    raf.seek(pos);
    raf.writeUTF(registro.equipo);
    pos += 20;

    raf.seek(pos);
    raf.writeInt(registro.puntos);
    pos += 4;
}
```

Comment: Como le decía Angel he probado ambos pero entiendo mejor el tuyo por el tema de la lista y la ordenación.

No me dicen que no pueda usar recursos como Compare etc.. Así que me gusta poder aprender nuevas formas de hacerlo.

Gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Como no se si puedes usar `Arrays sort` ni tampoco si puedes implementar `Comparator<Comparable[]>` para ordenar array te lo muestro de otra manera:

```
    raf = new RandomAccessFile("Partides.dat", "rw");

    int registros = (raf.length()/48); //(int)

    //Empleamos dos array para ordenar y otro como apoyo para este fin
    int[] tempArrayData = new int[registros];
    int[] tempArrayPos  = new int[registros];

    int count = 0;

    for (long i = 44; i < raf.length() -4; i = i+48){

     raf.seek(i);
     int valorI = raf.readInt();

     tempArrayData[count] = valorI;
     tempArrayPos[count]  = i;

     count ++;
    }

    //en este punto es donde ordenamos los arrays   

    int a       = 0;
    int tmpData = 0;
    int tmpPos  = 0;
    boolean swa = true;

    while (swa) {

        swa = false;
        a++;

        for (int i = 0; i < tempArrayData.length - a; i++) {
            if (tempArrayData[i] > tempArrayData[i + 1]) {

                tmpData              = tempArrayData[i];
                tempArrayData[i]     = tempArrayData[i + 1];
                tempArrayData[i + 1] = tmpData;

                tempPos             = tempArrayPos[i];
                tempArrayPos[i]     = tempArrayPos[i + 1];
                tempArrayPos[i + 1] = tmpPos;

                swa = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //el array tempArrayPos contiene las posiciones ordenadas con respecto a los registros de menor a mayor, si el registro 4 es el de menor puntuacion estara en la posicion 0 del array
    //el array tempArrayData contiene las puntuaciones ordenadas como las anteriores 

    //en este punto, la pregunta que me surje es si usted tiene que guardar las puntuaciones ordenadas con sus ID ect asociadas en un nuevo archivo.dat,
    //o en el .dat existente,
    //o basta con que en este punto se muestren ordenadas con un println por ejemplo.

    //Muestra
    for (int a = tempArrayPos.length(); a > -1; a--){ 

        raf.seek((tempArrayPos[a]) - 44);
        System.out.println(raf.readInt()); 

        raf.seek((tempArrayPos[a]) - 40);
        System.out.println(raf.readUTF());

        raf.seek((tempArrayPos[a]) - 20);
        System.out.println(raf.readUTF());

        raf.seek(tempArrayPos[a]);
        System.out.println(raf.readInt());
    }
    //crea un nuevo dat
    RandomAccessFile rafNew = new RandomAccessFile("PartidesOrdenades.dat", "rw");
    int posNew = 0;   

    for (int a = tempArrayPos.length(); a > -1; a--){ 

    rafNew.seek(posNew);
    raf.seek((tempArrayPos[a]) - 44);

    rafNew.writeInt(raf.readInt());
    posNew += 4;
    //
    rafNew.seek(posNew);
    raf.seek((tempArrayPos[a]) - 40);

    rafNew.writeUTF(raf.readUTF());
    posNew += 20;
    //
    rafNew.seek(posNew);
    raf.seek((tempArrayPos[a]) - 20);

    rafNew.writeUTF(raf.readUTF());
    posNew += 20;
    //
    rafNew.seek(posNew);
    raf.seek(tempArrayPos[a]);

    rafNew.writeInt(raf.readInt());
    posNew += 4;
    }

    rafNew.close();
raf.close();
```

Como te comente este codigo no ha sido compilado, si funciona sin fallos que no lo descarto, pero seria extraño, aun asi te lo puedes tomar como pseudo code, por otro lado puedes leer algunas de las dudas en los comentarios dentro del codigo, espero que te sirva o por lo menos te ayude.

Comment: He probado el tuyo y el de Paul y me funcionan igual!

Lo que entiendo mejor el de Paul.. a mi los arrays me despistan.. Por eso voy a usar el suyo pero ambos son geniales!

Gracias por la ayuda! Era el último ejercicio que tenía para el proyecto final! Mil gracias de verdad!